# Parametrization of $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2+e^2+f^2$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Is there an existing parametrization of the equation above that is similar to Brahmagupta's identity for $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$? I need either a reference to look it up or a hint to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: There is no $3$-square theorem, I you mean that.

Comment: Could you give a link to Bramagupta's identity? (I'm interested in whether it gives all the solutions of $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ in a parametric form, like the known one for $x^2+y^2=z^2.$]

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889062/solve-f2-e2-d2-c2-b2a2/889139#889139

Comment: Like Brahmagupta's identity: 

$$\left( {p}^{2}+{k}^{2}+{b}^{2}\right) \,\left( {s}^{2}+{h}^{2}+{f}^{2}\right) ={\left( p\,s+b\,h\right) }^{2}+{\left( k\,s+b\,f\right) }^{2}+{\left( b\,s-h\,p-f\,k\right) }^{2}+{\left( f\,p-h\,k\right) }^{2}$$

taking into account different signs will get four equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a parameterization for every equal sums of squares equation
$$
X_1^2 + \dotsb + X_m^2 = Y_1^2 + \dotsb + Y_n^2
$$
with $n,m$ positive integers and all $X_i,Y_i$ integers. The papers by [Barnett](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2302941?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) and [Bradley](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3620159?origin=JSTOR-pdf&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) are my first recommendations.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check them out. I can't open those files now on the mobile app. Just curious, do they give all the possible solutions?

Comment: Yes. They give formulas (with derivations) for general $n,m$, and then work out specific cases of $n$ and $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Above equation (a^2+b^2+c^2)=(d^2+e^2+f^2) has parametric solution. 
Refer to Tito piezas on line book "collection of algebraic Identities".
Section sum of squares. The answer is given below;

(a,b,c)=[(p+q),(r+s),(t+u)]  and

(d,e,f)=[(p-q),(r-s),(t-u)]

Condition is (pq+rs+tu)=0

After parametrization of (pq+rs+tu)=0, the parametric solution in 
one variable is given below:

(a,b,c)=[(4k^2+12k+1),(3k-8),(7k+28)]    and

(d,e,f)=[(4k^2+12k-13),(k+2),(13k+26)]

---